# Duplicated blocks of @Autowired beans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC application. Each controller of the application auto-wires the `@Service` components it needs to interact with. A Sonarqube analysis has detected that there was some duplication in this: some controllers may use the same services, in which case the `@Autowired` annotation and the corresponding fields are indeed the same.

For instance, the following would be duplicated in many controllers:

```
@Autowired
private FooService fooService;

@Autowired
private BarService barService;
```

This is a minor issue, and I don't know whether/how I should address this. Since all my controllers inherit an `AbstractController`, and all services are singletons, would it make sense to put all `@Autowired` elements in the base class, in protected fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dependencies already are in the subclasses, you probably have a reason for that, e.g. they do not conceptually belong in the abstract class. Keep them in the subclass if so.

It's important to adhere to the DRY principle, but don't be fanatic about it. Duplicating code gives you flexibility, and class dependencies are a typical place where you want such flexibility. Not to mention that the code is simpler with such duplication.

Static code analysis is good for providing pointers to improve your code, but they shouldn't be followed blindly.

Comment: You make a good point, and I think that consistency is indeed important. That gave me some food for thought, too - procedural design vs. OO principles. Thanks for your answer.